# Can i have multiple libs.versions.toml files in multi flavored android project?

Tags: android, kotlin

My Android App have multiple flavors based on countries , i want to build particular set of dependencies based on country flavor and i am using version catalog for dependencies management so i am thinking if i can have multiple libs.versions.toml and i use libs.versions.toml based on country so that it only have dependencies it want

this is my libs.version.toml

```
[versions]
agp = "8.2.0-alpha11"
kotlin = "1.8.10"
core-ktx = "1.9.0"
junit = "4.13.2"
androidx-test-ext-junit = "1.1.5"
espresso-core = "3.5.1"
lifecycle-runtime-ktx = "2.6.1"
activity-compose = "1.7.0"
compose-bom = "2023.03.00"
uiautomator = "2.2.0"
benchmark-macro-junit4 = "1.2.0-alpha16"
appcompat = "1.6.1"
material = "1.8.0"

[libraries]
core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "core-ktx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-test-ext-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "androidx-test-ext-junit" }
espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espresso-core" }
lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx" }
activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activity-compose" }
compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "compose-bom" }
ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
uiautomator = { group = "androidx.test.uiautomator", name = "uiautomator", version.ref = "uiautomator" }
benchmark-macro-junit4 = { group = "androidx.benchmark", name = "benchmark-macro-junit4", version.ref = "benchmark-macro-junit4" }
appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
kotlinAndroid = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
androidTest = { id = "com.android.test", version.ref = "agp" }

[bundles]
```

Note : I am using Kotlin DSL for build files

If anyone has any suggestion how can i achieve this
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Gradle will report an warning if you're importing multiple toml files. Actually it works but its not recommended.

Comment: yes it is working , do we have any other option than this ?

Comment: migrate to single file.

Comment: i want separate file for all flavors to manage different dependencies